# SVM Kernel's O(n) time

Tags: machine-learning, svm, machine-learning-model, kernel-methods

I can't understand how computing kernel, K(x,z) takes only linear time despite working in O(n^d) dimensional space.
Please explain me. I'm a newbie in ML.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compute `K(x, z)`, you have to:

- Perform `O(n)` multiplications `x1 * z1`, `x2 * x2`, ..., `xn * zn`,
- Perform `O(n)` additions `(x1 * z1) + (x2 * x2) + ... + (xn * zn)`,
- Perform two `O(1)` operations `_ + c` and `_ ^ d`.

Thus, computing `K(x, z) = (dot(x, z) + c)^d` takes `O(n)` time.

It's completely normal that the feature space has much higher dimension than the time it takes to compute the kernel: otherwise we wouldn't need the kernels in the first place, because we could just compute the feature vectors directly.

If you want a more extreme example, take a look at `K(x, y) = min(x, y)` on non-negative real numbers `x, y`. It takes constant time to evaluate `min(x, y)`. However, the feature space is `L^2(R)` (square-integrable functions on the real line, with the standard Hilbert-space scalar product), and the feature mapping is `phi(x) = chi_{[0, x]}`, where `chi_{[0, x]}` denotes the characteristic function of the interval `[0, x]`. Thus, the feature space is infinite-dimensional, but the time it takes to evaluate the kernel is constant.